# cannot delete in MEAN Stack - Angular 13 - Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: mongodb, express, angular13

I'm tryring to delete a employee from a collection but it throw me this error

### Error

Error: src/app/components/employee/employee.component.html:72:68 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

72             <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEmployee(employee._id)">

***employee.model.ts***

```
export interface Employee {
    name: string,
    office: string,
    position: string,
    salary: number,
    createdAt?: string,
    updatedAt?: string,
    _id?: string
}
```

***employee.component.ts***

```
deleteEmployee(_id: string){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')){
      this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(_id).subscribe({
        next: (res)=>{
          this.getEmployees();
        },
        error: (e)=> console.log(e)
      })
    }
  }
```

***employee.component.html***

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeeService.employees">
          <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.position }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.office }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">
              <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEmployee(employee._id)">
              <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

***employee.service.ts***

```
deleteEmployee( _id: string){
    return this.http.delete(`${this.URL_API}/${_id}`)}
```

*Server Side -*
***employees.controller.js***

```
employeeCrtl.deleteEmployee = async (req, res) => {
    await Employee.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.json({status: 'Employee Deleted'})
}
```

***Employee.js***

```
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    position: {type: String, required: true},
    office: {type: String, required: true},
    salary: {type: Number, required: true},
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
})

module.exports = model("Employee", employeeSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from here. When you declare `id?`, which means `id` is an [optional variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) and has the type  `T | undefined`.

```js
export interface Employee {
    ...
    _id?: string
}
```

To solve it, you have to remove the question mark from `id`.

```js
export interface Employee {
    ...
    _id: string
}
```